# Mediawiki - Links not showing up in galleries

Tags: gallery, hyperlink, mediawiki, image-gallery

I made a gallery in MediaWiki with this code:

```
<gallery caption="a caption" captionalign="center" bordersize="medium" perrow=4 widths="110">
File:blabla1.jpg|'''Caption1'''|link=Page 1
File:blabla2.jpg|'''Caption2'''|link=Page 2
</gallery>
```

Ok, the gallery works, but the caption of the first image is: **Caption1**|link=Page 1

And the caption of the second image is: **Caption2**|link=Page 1

So the links are not recognized and are included in the caption

What can be wrong? I am using MediaWiki 1.19, I've also tried to write `File:blabla2.jpg|link=Page 2|'''Caption2'''` with no results

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug in 1.19.  You should upgrade, because this seems to work in later versions.

Here is a sample of it working in MW 1.22: https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Project:Sandbox&oldid=803401

Comment: Mmm, I think this version is still supported...I'll try to ask on MediaWiki forum, I can't upgrade because of my PHP version

Comment: 1.19 is still supported, but we aren't backporting all fixes.  Come ask at the Support Desk (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Project:Support_desk) and I'll give you the same answer. :)